# UTF-8 Encoding in Ruby using a variable

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 (and upgrading isn't an option).  I would like to create a string of all UTF-8 code points from 0 to 127, written as "\uXXXX".

My problem is that this is being interpreted as (for example): 'u0008'. If I try to use '\u0008', the string becomes "\u0008" which IS NOT what I want.

I have tried many different ways, but it seems impossible to create a string that is exactly just "\uXXXX" ie. "\u000B".  it always is either "\u000B" or "u000B"

Escaping the '\' isn't an option. I need to send a string to a server, such that the server will receive '\u000B' for example.  It is so that other server can test its parsing of the \uXXXX syntax.  This seems impossible to do in Ruby however.

Happy if someone can prove me wrong :)

Comment: Just to make that clear: The UTF-8 code points from 0 to 127 are the exact same as for ASCII. You don't need to go through complicated steps to create them.

Comment: What exactly do you want the expected result to be? Please provide a sample of what the data is that you're looking for.

Comment: To clarify, what I actually expect is value to have, for example: "U+1 = \u0001, hex = \x01, U+117 = \u0075, hex = \x75"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Integer #`[`chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Integer.html#M000061) to get the character. Here's a clean version:

```
(1..127).each do |i|
  value << "U+#{i} = #{i.chr}, hex = \\x#{"%02x" % i}; "
end
```

The `"%02x" % i` is the equal to `sprintf("%02x", i)`. It returns the integer as a 2-digit hexadecimal number.

Escaped output (see comments):

```
(1..127).each do |i|
  value << "U+#{i} = \\u#{"%04x" % i}, hex = \\x#{"%02x" % i}; "
end
```

Comment: Yes this works.  I would like to add that for code points less than 128, ASCII and UTF-8 are identical so there is no need to worry about Unicode or ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: To clarify, what I actually expect is value to have, for example: "U+1 = \u0001, hex = \x01, U+117 = \u0075, hex = \x75".  What the above gives me is "U+1 = \0001, hex = \\x01, U+117 = \0075, hex = \\x75" which is not what I want.  I need the \u because I need the strings to be JSON escaped.

Comment: Also, to add to this, I cannot use "\x" << str because I get a warning about an invalid escape character sequence.  But if I use '\x' << str, I get \\x and the string isn't properly converted to hex

Comment: Ya, sorry about that.  I have clarified my problem in the description.  Any ideas?